# Trying to connect android app to mySQL but its not connecting

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin

I am trying to connect a simple register page to mySQL using Kotlin, I have the php setup and it all works fine and inputs data when actually put into the URL using my PC browser and the chrome browser on the emulator but it just wont work from the app.

```
        Log.d("DownloadURL:",DownloadURL)

        val name =URLEncoder.encode(etName.text.toString(),"utf-8")
        DownloadURL=URLEncoder.encode(DownloadURL,"utf-8")
        val url="http://10.0.2.2/fitnessappdb/register.php?user_name="+ etName.text.toString() + "&user_email="+ etEmail.text.toString() +  "&user_password="+ etPassword.text.toString() +"&user_image="+ DownloadURL
        MyAsyncTask().execute(url)
    }

}

fun SplitString(email:String):String{
    val split= email.split("@")
    return split[0]
}


// CALL HTTP
inner class MyAsyncTask: AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        //Before task started
    }
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        try {

            val url=URL(p0[0])

            val urlConnect=url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            urlConnect.connectTimeout=7000
            val op=Operations()

            var inString= op.ConvertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
            //Cannot access to ui
            publishProgress(inString)
        }catch (ex:Exception){}


        return " "

    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        try{
            var json=JSONObject(values[0])
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,json.getString("msg"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            if (json.getString("msg")== "user is added"){
                finish()
            }else{
                buRegister.isEnabled=true
            }

        }catch (ex:Exception){}
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

        //after task done
    }


}


// Progress Dialog

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is port. Could yo try to add port number to URL like "http://10.0.2.2:80" I had same problem then i fix it with this.
Sorry for answer i cant comment for now

Comment: That didn't work, its getting as far as collecting the url but not opening it